# How to specify index of canvas instructions in kivy language

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

How do I specify the order the canvas instructions are drawn in from the kv file?

Eg. how would i make the ellipse in the Bar rule be drawn before the rectangle in the root?

```
Foo:
    canvas:
       Rectangle:
           size: self.size
           pos: self.pos

<Bar>:
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
           size: self.size
           pos: self.pos
```

Comment: Try playing around with `canvas.before` and `canvas.after` in place of `canvas`.

Comment: @Erik That's really useful thanks. Do you know if there is a way to construct more instruction groups?

Comment: I think that's all there is. Generally you would have children widgets being drawn on top of their parents, so your use case is reversed in a sense. Maybe you can find a way to switch the logic?

Comment: @Erik Thanks for your help. I ended up just redoing the order of adding widgets, which has made the whole thing less efficient but now works. Turns out before and after don't seem to work between separate rules. This seems to be one of the few bits of kivy that isn't (imao) very well implemented in the kv language